# Need help proving this entailment where the KB has sentences with multiple conjuncts

Tags: propositional-calculus

Show formally (using a proof rather than a Truth Table) that A follows from the given sentences shown.

1. P ∧ Z
2. (¬R ∧ ¬W) ∨ (¬P)
3. (W ∧ Q) ⇒ P
4. Q ∨ W
5. Q ⇒ (A ∨ P)
6. (P ∧ Q) ⇒ (A ∨ R)

In other words, we need to prove KB ⊨ A, where KB is the collection of sentences.  I'll use Resolution Theorem Proving for this proof, and to prove that KB ⊨ A, we need to show that KB ∧ ¬A is unsatisfiable. That is, KB ∧ ¬A is True in NO models.

Resolution Theorem Proving Steps:

Convert KB ∧ ¬A into CNF

1. Apply the resolution rule whenever possible and add the result as an additional clause in the conjunction
2. Repeat step 2 until either:
    a. No new clauses can be added: KB does not entail A
    b. Two clauses resolve to yield the empty clause: KB entails A

Converting the KB to CNF:

Number Sentence
1            P ∧ Z       given, already in CNF

1            (P) ∧ (Z)  Associativity

2            (¬R ∧ ¬W) ∨ (¬P)          Given

2            (¬R ∨ ¬P) ∧ (¬W ∨ ¬P) Distributivity of ∨ over ∧

3            (W ∧ Q) ⇒ P    Given

3           ¬(W ∧ Q) ∨ P    Implication elimination

3           (¬W ∨ ¬Q) ∨ P  DeMorgan

3           (¬W ∨ ¬Q ∨ P)  Associativity, now in CNF

4            Q ∨ W       Given

4            (Q ∨ W)     Associativity

5            Q ⇒ (A ∨ P)     Given

5            ¬Q ∨ (A ∨ P)    Implication elimination

5            (¬Q ∨ A ∨ P)    Associativity

6            (P ∧ Q) ⇒ (A ∨ R)     Given

6            ¬(P ∧ Q) ∨ (A ∨ R)    Implication Elimination

6            (¬P ∨ ¬Q) ∨ (A ∨ R)  DeMorgan

6            (¬P ∨ ¬Q ∨ A ∨ R)    Associativity

7            ¬A      Negated query

KB in CNF:

1            (P) ∧ (Z)
2            (¬R ∨ ¬P) ∧ (¬W ∨ ¬P)
3            (¬W ∨ ¬Q ∨ P)
4            (Q ∨ W)
5            (¬Q ∨ A ∨ P)
6            (¬P ∨ ¬Q ∨ A ∨ R)
7            ¬A

I'm stuck at how to come up with a contradiction. Mainly stuck in resolving variables where there are two conjuncts as in (¬R ∨ ¬P) ∧ (¬W ∨ ¬P) (2) and (P) ∧ (Z) (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, we have to remove $\land$ and $\to$, using many times [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) equivalence as well as [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) on 2) to get:

1a) $P$

1b) $Z$

2a) $¬R ∨ ¬P$

2b) $¬W ∨ ¬P$

3) $¬ W ∨ ¬Q ∨ P$

4) $Q ∨ W$

5) $¬Q ∨ A ∨ P$

6) $¬P ∨ ¬Q ∨ A ∨ R$

> 7) $¬A$

---

Now apply [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) to 1a) and 2a) to get $¬R$ and 1a) and 2b) to get $¬W$.

Use $¬W$ with 4) to get $Q$.

Finally, use $P, Q$ and $¬R$ with 6) to get $A$.

Comment: Is it allowed to use the same sentence, say 1a, twice to form new sentences?

Comment: @LeonardoLopez - the [Resolution proof procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique) is aimed at automated theorem proving (i.e. to be performed by a machine) : "The resolution rule is applied to **all possible pairs of clauses** that contain complementary literals. After each application of the resolution rule, the resulting sentence is simplified by removing repeated literals."